# Skobbler returns empty advices list

Tags: android, skmaps

In Skobbler Route calculation, I'm getting only the list of route coordinates.

Code,

```
private void launchRouteCalculation(SKCoordinate startPoint, SKCoordinate destinationPoint) {
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().clearAllRoutesFromCache();
    // get a route object and populate it with the desired properties
    SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
    route.setStartCoordinate(startPoint);
    route.setRequestAdvices(true);
    route.setDestinationCoordinate(destinationPoint);
    route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
    route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
    route.setRouteExposed(true);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
}
```

In `onRouteCalculationCompleted` and `onAllRoutesCompleted`, I'm trying to get a list of advices. But it returns `null` always.

And also when starting navigation, I'm not getting correct `SKNavigationState` in `onUpdateNavigationState` method. Kindly help.

Comment: Most probably you are not correctly connecting the listeners - can you reproduce your issue in the demo project?

Answer (score 0):

This my working code to get advices list.
First step - start routes calculation:

```
SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
route.setStartCoordinate(startLoc);
route.setDestinationCoordinate(destinationLoc);
route.setNoOfRoutes(3);
route.setExtendedPointsReturned(true);
route.setRequestAdvices(true);
route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
route.setRouteExposed(true);
route.setRequestAdvices(true);
rm.setRouteListener(this);
final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = new SKAdvisorSettings();
advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_RU);
advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(activity.getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/Advisor");
advisorSettings.setResourcePath(activity.getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/Advisor/Languages");
advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("ru");
advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.AUDIO_FILES);
rm.setAudioAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
rm.calculateRoute(route);
```

Second step - make request to get advices list when routes calculated successful:

```
//better execute this code in background thread
List<RoutePoint> points = new ArrayList<RoutePoint>();
SKRouteManager rm = SKRouteManager.getInstance();
int id = data.routesInfo.get(currentRouteIndex).id; //because i set 3 routes in calculation step and use ui selection of routes. "currentRouteIndex" should be 0, 1 or 2
List<SKRouteAdvice> ri = rm.getAdviceList(id, SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER_METERS);
for (SKRouteAdvice aRi : ri) {
    RoutePoint point = new RoutePoint(); // my custom advice class object, use class what you need or just save list of SKRouteAdvice items
    point.distanceMeters = aRi.getDistanceToAdvice();
    point.instruction = aRi.getAdviceInstruction();
    point.street = aRi.getStreetName();
    point.image_path = aRi.getVisualAdviceFile();
    point.durationSec = aRi.getTimeToAdvice();
    point.id = aRi.getAdviceID();
    points.add(point);
}
data.routePoints = points;
```